# Quotation found (escaped) in string is not being printed in result

Tags: excel, csv, arduino

I am creating a datalogger. It needs to record data and formulas in CSV format, for later import into Excel.

I almost have it working, but on import into Excel, one of my inner (literal) quotations goes missing. And (likely as a result) my string gets split into two cells by the following comma in the string.

Raw formula I would like to see in the cell:

```
=AVERAGE(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN())&":"&ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN())))
```

Code:

```
String formula = "\"=AVERAGE(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-3,COLUMN())&\":\"&ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN())))\"";
dataFile.println(formula);
```

Result in Excel:

```
Cell 1: =AVERAGE(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-3,COLUMN())&:"&ADDRESS(ROW()-1
Cell 2: COLUMN())))"
```

How do I properly escape that quotation? I always thought it was just " \" ". And will that solve my comma separating issue?

Comment: String formula = "\"=AVERAGE(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-3,COLUMN())&\"\":\"\"&ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN())))\""; just worked, no idea why.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a specification of the CSV format, but [RFC 4180](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) suggests that entries containing the separator (comma) should be enclosed in quotes and that quotes in quoted entries should be doubled up. But you've just found that out.

Comment: @pnuts: I'm using excel to open the csvs, thought maybe it's having issues. Figured I'd include it just in case.

Comment: That language is not C.  I'll suppose it is actually C#, based on the context and on the confusion with C (tags edited), but it could also be Java.

Comment: It's Arduino, the datalogger is a physical device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSV Spec requires double-quotes to be escaped with additional double-quotes.  The string should end up being

`"=AVERAGE(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-3,COLUMN())&"":""&ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN())))"`

You will need to add the appropriate c# escapes but that should take care of the issue.

```
string MyString = "\"=AVERAGE(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-3,COLUMN())&\"\":\"\"&ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN())))\""
```

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180

> 7. If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote
>    appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with
>    another double quote.  For example:
>
>    "aaa","b""bb","ccc"